# "No matching signature found" error in python scipy ndimage.label() function used with boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, boolean, ndimage

I have a boolean array to indicate dry days:

```
dry_bool

0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
...  
15336    False
15337    False
15338    False
15339    False
15340    False
Name: budget, Length: 15341, dtype: object
```

The number of False and True values are:

```
dry_bool.value_counts()

False    14594
True       747
Name: budget, dtype: int64
```

I want to find contiguous periods of dry days (where dry_bool=True).
Using the ndimage.label() function by the scipy package

`import scipy.ndimage as ndimage`

`events, n_events = ndimage.label(dry_bool)`

gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[76], line 2
      1 # Find contiguous regions of dry_bool = True
----> 2 events, n_events = ndimage.label(dry_bool)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/_measurements.py:219, in label(input, structure, output)
    216         return output, maxlabel
    218 try:
--> 219     max_label = _ni_label._label(input, structure, output)
    220 except _ni_label.NeedMoreBits as e:
    221     # Make another attempt with enough bits, then try to cast to the
    222     # new type.
    223     tmp_output = np.empty(input.shape, np.intp if need_64bits else np.int32)

File _ni_label.pyx:202, in _ni_label._label()

File _ni_label.pyx:239, in _ni_label._label()

File _ni_label.pyx:95, in _ni_label.__pyx_fused_cpdef()

TypeError: No matching signature found
```

which I cannot wrap my head around. Any clue what's going on?

There are definitely consecutive dry days, as you can see when I read the indices of the True values in the dry_bool array:

```
dry_idcs = [i for i, x in enumerate(dry_bool) if x]
print(dry_idcs[0:10])

[165, 205, 206, 214, 229, 230, 262, 281, 292, 301]
```

Comment: please provide a minimum viable portion of your code that triggers this error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the  most important line of code, I'm still new to writing questions on here! ... I edited the question with the missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet it says `dtype: object`, even though it's supposed to be an array of data type boolean (not object). Given that your error message gives you a `TypeError`, maybe that's the problem?

You could try explicitly converting the data type of your array:

```py
dry_bool = dry_bool.astype(bool)
```

If you provide more of your code (e.g. how you create/populate the array `dry_bool`) it's easier to figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: thank you so much! This solved the problem. And sorry I forgot some important lines of code, I edited the question with some missing code snippets. I'm still new to asking questions on here, learning by doing! Since your answer solved the problem I won't go into detail about how I populated the array for now.